# Running .exe with parameters from Java

Tags: java

If I run the following command from windows cmd, it creates a .clm file:

```
hclm_build_model -p params_even.params -o lleven_regression.clm -g
```

I am trying to run this from within a Java class, and based on previous replies I am using:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("hclm4\\hclm_build_model.exe", "-p", "params_even.params", "-o", "lleven_regression.clm", "-g").start();
```

Note that I usually run from cmd by being inside the hclm4 for directory, whereas my class is one level above.

The code exits with status 0, but no file is created which leads me to believe that there is something going wrong.

Any advice?

Comment: You probably need to call [ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29), since you're not interested in capturing the output in the Java program, which is the default mode.

Comment: Your file is created in the active directory, which is were the JVM has been started from. It may be your developer tool if you are using one. ProcessBuilder can change the active directory.

Comment: @Andreas that worked, but, because you answer is a comment, I can't accept it :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29), since you're not interested in capturing the output in the Java program.

The default I/O mode is [`Redirect.PIPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html#PIPE), which is used to pipe command input from your Java program (rarely used), and to pipe command output (and error output) to your Java program.

The command is trying to write output, and is initially waiting for your Java program to retrieve it. When your Java program then terminates, the command gets a write error on the pipe, which causes the command to terminate, before it got around to do the desired job.